# Create front page with background with typst and quarto

Tags: r, quarto, typst

I'm experimenting with quarto and typst to create a report with an image as background on only the front page. I managed to get an image as background for all pages, but I would like the background only on the front (with a title on top of it). Is this possible with typst?

This would be implemented in a template.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible code?

Comment: I am on a similar journey. What I get from the **typst** documentation is that you can somehow define styling for "subset of pages". Thus, I assume the way forward would be to use `raw typst` in a chunk, e.g. ```{=typst} ....``` to set the (i) front page and then (ii) the following pages. Via the template settings one can prob move the TOC to later pages, etc. But I am shooting here from the hip. Could you share what you have done so far?